# When publishing from AWS event bridge to SNS as a rule target is it possible to add MessageAttributes to allow subscription filtering?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

I have an event bridge rule which sends events to an SNS Topic as a target. This works fine. However, I would like subscribers of the topic to have the ability to use subscription filtering, but it appears event bridge does not set MessageAttributes in SNS, so there is nothing to filter on.

Is it possible to set MessageAttributes when publishing events from event bridge to an SNS Topic when the topic is an event rule target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly this is not possible. You would have to proxy through a lambda function:

```
EventBridge --> Lambda (add attributes) --> SNS
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter by MessageBody instead of MessageAttributes

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html